# How do I center an image?

Tags: html, css, center

Shouldn't this image be centered? If not, how do I center it?

```
<div class="logo-area">
<div class="logo-bg">
    <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.jpg" align="middle" /></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

The `align` attribute is deprecated and should not be used.
Try this instead:

```
<img src="images/logo.jpg" style="display: block; margin: 0 auto;" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Set `text-align:center` on the image's parent div.

```css
.logo-bg {
    text-align:center;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/G9LZX/)**

Answer (score 1):

The `align` tag is deprecated. Use CSS, e.g.

```
 <img style="margin: 0 auto;" .... />
```

Comment: `img` needs display:block for this to work -- see Ross's answer.

Answer (score 0):

`align="middle"` doesn't exist but `align="center"` although it's deprecated

Consider using `style="text-align : center"` instead  on the block tag containing the image `<div class="logo-bg">`

Answer (score 0):

No, not like that. LIke this:

```
<div class="logo-bg" style="text-align:center">
    <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.jpg" align="middle" /></a>
</div>
```

(but better to put the style in a style-sheet, of course).

Answer (score 0):

You can use center tag instead of css styling
like this,

```
<div class="logo-area">
  <center><a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo.jpg" align="middle" /></a></center>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

On the .logo-area container class make sure it has a width, then apply a margin: 0 auto; to the .logo-bg class.

```
.logo-area{
  width: 250px;  
 }
.logo-bg{
  width: 0 auto;  
 }
```